# PBS : Fill up all cores in a node before going to the next node

Tags: cluster-computing, job-scheduling, hpc, pbs

By default PBS submits my serial jobs to all the nodes in a queue before using up more resources(cpus) from the nodes.

Can I force PBS to submit my jobs to one node till it exhausts all the CPUS of that node (say 12 cpus; also given that the memory requirement of 12 serial jobs is less than the memory assigned to each node) before it submits the 13th job to the next node.

I want to do this so that later when I want to submit a job with higher memory requirement, I don't go into 'queue' mode because all the nodes have some jobs running.

Ideally I should have separate queues for this purpose but I want my queues to be dynamic in the sense that I may require more large mem jobs which I cant run because though small memory queue is not being used fully, it has some jobs running on all nodes.

Comment: What scheduler are you using?

Comment: Node allocation depends on the scheduler used. If you are using OpenPBS in combination with Maui, then the allocation policy could be set as described [here](http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/maui/5.2nodeallocation.php). `FIRSTAVAILABLE` or `CONTIGUOUS` should do the trick. Note that this affects the cluster scheduling policy as a whole and not only a specific subset of jobs.

Comment: Another trick is to make sure that you don't have NODEACCESSPOLICY SINGLEJOB set in your configuration (for Maui, if you're using Maui).